# What falsifies a node in a semantic tree?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, trees

With set of Atoms, A = {p1, p2, p3}, and a formula in  CNF, let's say (~p1 & ~p2) OR (~p1 & p2 & p3) OR (~p2 & p3), if we draw a semantic Tree for this formula, what will falsify any node in the tree? I know the definition of a failure node and also of inference nodes. What I am trying to understand is, what is the ACTUAL operation at the node as a result of which it will be falsified. Is it an AND of two branches? Is it an OR of two branches?

Comment: See [Semantic trees](http://www.math.helsinki.fi/logic/opetus/log1/26_Logic_Predicate_Logic_sem_trees_text.pdf).

Comment: See also the post [How to prove that a formula is valid using semantic tableau](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767402/issue-proving-that-a-formula-is-valid-using-semantic-tableau)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prove a formula $A$ with *Semantic trees*, we have to start with $¬A$.

Then we apply the rules to "decompose" the formula : the choice of the rule is dictated by the main connective.

Thus, if we arrive at a node with a *conjunction* $(A_1 \land A_2)$ we have to apply the rule for $\land$ adding to the node a branch with both formulas $A_1$ and $A_2$.

If instead we have a node with a *disjunction* $(A_1 \lor A_2)$, we have to add two branches with $A_1$ and $A_2$ respectively.

To show that a node $A$ is *unsatisfiable*, we have to check that **all** branches starting from that nodes close i.e. that they contains both $B$ and $¬B$ for some formula $B$.

Comment: You always save the day, Mauro! This was really helpful, thank you so much.

Comment: @haris.a.amin - you are welcome :-)